# How I can parse email to get original recipient of an email?

Tags: c++, email, parsing, pop3, email-client

I had email source with me and want parse original recipient of email.

Lets say "user1@test.com" is receiving a email, but in "To" list user1@test.com, user2@test.com & user3@test.com are mentioned. I want to get only user1 from email source.

In initial analysis, email from mdeamon server contains "X-MDaemon-Deliver-To:" tag. Similarly email from Devcot mail server contains  "Delivered-To:". But not getting generic parsing logic to get original email recipient.

How I can parse email to get original recipient of an email?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best way to get this information is probably to parse the `Received` headers to see who the message was delivered for. In other words, look for a `Received` header that has a `for` token followed by `x@x.com` (where `x@x.com` will be the recipient).

Comment: Important note: the email often contains multiple Received headers, and it is important to know that they are added from bottom up, so the last line is the one that has been added first. The original email address may have been forwarded or aliased, that's why it is important, in order to find the original recipient, that you parse **the last Received header** that has a for token.